# Use native Node.JS code to get a WSO2 access_token

Tags: node.js, wso2, access-token

I have been trying to use native Node.JS code in Node 8 to get an access token from WSO2 with my client ID and client secret.
I receive the following error: Unsupported Client Authentication Method!

Here is my code:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const https = require('https');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'
});

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.somedomain.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (data) => {
     process.stdout.write(data);
  });
});

req.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

When I attempt to include another option parameter of 'auth' for the client ID and client secret then it tells me "TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object."

Any help on how to make this work is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `Authorization` header with the request. I'm no expert on javascript/node but the token generation works after adding the `Authorization` header in the `headers` section as below. I have used localhost for testing purpose.

```
var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from("nM_ftrK2pjoBW4JofE21xI1cP0Ya" + ':' + "jmFJIgC5QMDkU_HxQKiDUbp5UAca").toString('base64');

var options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8243,
    path: '/token',
    method: 'POST',

    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': postData.length,
        'Authorization': auth
    }
};
```

The correct value (`Authorization : Basic Base64(consumer-key:consumer-secret)`) should be passed in with the token request when invoking the token endpoint to get the access_token.